# Does WebSphere Class Loader Viewer show libraries loaded as the application is running or only libraries loaded at startup?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, classloader

In the WebSphere Application Server 6.0 admin console, I am going to Troubleshooting -> Class Loader Viewer -> server_name -> Applications and opening the class loader for a `war` file. I click the "Classes" link under "WAS Module - Compound Class Loader" and I see a list of classes loaded from corresponding `jar` files.

Will this list update as the application runs, more code branches are executed, and potentially more libraries are loaded or does it only show what was loaded at startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows the list of classes that have been loaded by that class loader at the time the page is loaded.  If you refresh the page, it will show any new classes loaded in the interim (including as more code branches are executed, as you say).